# How can I create this two arrays in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to create two array from mysql select query. One for residential address and other one for postal address.

This is my select query:

```
$prep_query = "SELECT address_type
                    , street_no
                    , street_name
                    , city
                FROM  addresses
                WHERE user_id = ?";                          
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_query);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);  
    $stmt->execute();    
    $stmt->store_result();  
    $stmt->bind_result( $address_type
                      , $street_no
                      , $street_name
                      , $city
                      );
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {      
        //echo '<pre>',print_r($row[$street_name]).'</pre>';
    }
}
```

Residential address is compulsory and postal address is optional for all users. So output from this query may be one row or two.

How to create two arrays for these two addresses?

Comment: How do you differentiate between residential and postal addresses? There's nothing in your query that will do so.

Comment: just create two arrays, push on both (containers) arrays accordingly, i'm guessing its in the `address_type`

Comment: @andrewsi, we can identify what is the address using `address type`.

Comment: @user3733831 - darn it, so it is. Apologies!

Comment: `address type` column is something like this - `address_type TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, # -- 1=Residencial 2=Postal`

Comment: @Ghost, Can you kindly show me it through an example.? Thank you.

Comment: @user3733831 just try to use the address type key `$user_info[$address_type] = $street_name;`, that should separate both addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very close.  Your "while" loop will iterate through any and all records in the result set.  So if there are 2 records returned (1 for the physical address and 1 for the P.O. Box address), it will operate on both.  (Don't worry if there is only 1 record; if so, it will only return 1 and only pass through that loop once.)

It looks like the "address_type" column may indicate whether the address is a physical or a post office address.  If so, just use an IF statement to check "$address_type" and then echo the appropriate output (or ELSE the other one).

You may also want to sort the records by address_type (showing the physical address first).  If so, just add "ORDER BY address_type" to the end of that SQL statement.